# AWS CloudWatchアラーム： 「『3時間』CPU使用率が5%以下の状態が続いたら」という条件を指定したい

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

## 環境

- AWS CloudWatch アラーム

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html
- AWS EC2

## やりたいこと

個人用に、EC2でサーバを起動しています。
料金を削減するために、EC2を使っていないときは、自動的に停止するようにしたいです。
具体的にはCloudWatchアラームで、自動的にEC2を停止させたいです。

## 質問

「『3時間』CPU使用率が5%以下の状態が続いたら」という条件の「3時間」は、どこで設定できますか？
時間を指定するセレクトボックスには、「5分、15分、1時間、6時間」しかなく、「3時間」はありませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 試したこと

「最低期間」に「3回連続で1時間」という条件を設定したら、使用していない時間が1時間続いたぐらいで、停止してしまいました。

Comment: これec2からのショートカット(?)でやろうとしてますよね？`CloudWatch`から`ルールを作成`して監視してはどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

36回×5分だとどうですか？

3回×1時間だと、180分の間に 3回しか チェックされないので、偶然 CPU負荷が低いときに 測定されてしまうと 使用中でも アラームが作動してしまう気がします。

36回×5分だと、5分おきにチェックされ、36回連続しなければアラームは作動しないので「使ってないとき」が 判定出来る気がします。

また、「平均」の場合は、5分間の平均値に 値が丸められますので、「最大」のほうが 期待する動作に近いかもしれません。EC2の用途によっては、CPUではなく、ディスクIOだったり、ネットワーク転送量で測定したほうが、正しく判定できることも考えられます。このへんはチューニングだと思いますので ちょうどいい設定を探してみてください。

Comment: 「36回×5分」で、やりたいことが実現できました。